# How to display colored text to players when they enter a certain area/coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a map and I'm trying to make something like this:

I need a command that will run when anyone enters certain area/coordinates, it will display colored text. I tried every command that I *guessed* it will work.(`/execute` **-**/`tellraw` **-**`/testfor`) But it didn't work. This is another example of what I tried: `**\tellraw** command (*Colored Text*)`

An example of what I'm trying to do:

If anybody enters `10 60 10` to `50 60 10` coordinates, a red colored text will say: 
"You're about to fall down!"

What is a functioning command

Comment: What is the actual command you tried?

Comment: Are you sure the range is from height 60 to height 60? That would mean that players who jump would be excluded.

Comment: Should it happen every time the enter or just once?

Comment: May not be possible without a large number of command blocks, will a radius work instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might know! You have to do radius though, here is the command:

```
/execute @a[x=-30,y=60,z=10,r=2] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @p ["",{"text":"You're about to fall down!","color":"dark_red"}]
```

EDIT: You have to put it in a command block that is `Repeat` `Unconditional` and `Always Active`, you can put it anywhere.

Comment: FYI you should not be using `/execute` like that. Only use `/execute` when the origin or executor needs to be changed, which is not the case here. Just move the selector from `/execute` into `/tellraw`. Also be aware that this just spams the player's chat rather than plays a single time when they enter the area.

Comment: You're right but he can make something that prevents it from spamming.